# SwiftUI: Improve performance of views with many images

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a SwiftUI view that consists of a TabView that has multiple pages containing a VStack with multiple Views of type SubView. Those contain around 10 images each with a size of 256 x 256 pixels. The code below provides a minimum viable example:

```
struct MainView: View {
 
 @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
 
 var body: some View {
     TabView {
         ForEach(0..<5) { i in
             VStack {
                 ForEach(0..<5) { j in
                     SubView(model: viewModel.models[j])
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     .tabViewStyle(.page)
 }
}


struct SubView: View {
 
 var model: Model
 
 var body: some View {
     VStack(spacing: 0) {
         HStack {
             Image(uiImage: model.image)
                 .renderingMode(.original)
                 .resizable()
                 .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                 .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                 .clipShape(Circle())
                 .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
             
             VStack {
                 Text(model.name)
                     .fontWeight(.bold)
                     .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                     .lineLimit(2)
                     .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
             }
         }
         .frame(height: 70)
         
         HStack {
             GeometryReader { geometry in
                 TabView {
                     ForEach(0..<model.smallImages.count, id: \.self){i in
                         HStack {
                             Image(uiImage: model.smallImages[i])
                                 .renderingMode(.original)
                                 .resizable()
                                 .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                 .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                 .background(.white)
                                 .clipShape(Circle())
                             
                             Text("Some short text")
                                 .scaledToFit()
                                 .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                                 .lineLimit(2)
                                 .frame(width: max(geometry.size.width - 60, 0), alignment: .leading)
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
             }
         }
         .frame(height: 40)
     }
     
 }
}
```

The problem is that when I switch between the pages of the main TabView, there is always a slight lag. My guess is that this has to do with the rendering of the images since the switching is noticably smoother without them. Is there a way to improve the performance for example by rendering the images on a background thread similar to what AsyncImage is doing for images from a URL? Are there other ways to improve the performance? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
This is the code of the Model:

```
struct Model: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image: UIImage?
    let name: String
    let smallImages: [UIImage?] 
    let smallNames: [String] 
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let foregroundColor: Color
}
```

Comment: "My guess is that this has to do with the rendering of the images" Have you used Instruments to prove this?

Comment: I have turned off the images of the SubViews and it was much smoother.

Comment: Did you try to use `LazyVStack` / `LazyHStack`?

Comment: @rapiddevice yes but unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: Please don't add the Xcode tag. Your question is not about the use of Xcode. Please read the tag information.

Comment: How are your images stored? Can you share more code of your model?

Comment: In that case your issue may not be just rendering of the images: could be calculation of the dynamic sizes of the frames and what not. Try to replace images with, say, SF symbols, and see if it's equally slow. If it is, then review view hierarchy and start disabling parts of the frame rendering. `GeometryReader` is a good candidate for slowness, since it needs to recalc on each rendering (test by replacing it with static frame sizes). Also I have never seen so many `TabView`s used on one screen - no idea what that would do... In short, you need to figure out what takes time...

Comment: @koen I have edited the question with the code of the model.

Comment: You could remove the view model object and use `@State` which is the same thing

Comment: @pregmatch Unfortunately not really. I basically just tried to use LazyVStacks and reduced computed variables. I found that especially the latter slows everything down a lot because they get recomputed way too often by SwiftUI without anything actually changing.